# HTML button to execute python code

Tags: python, html, networking

I am using flask to run my python code when html button is pressed. My python code takes an encoded image and returns the encoded text by decoding it.Now what I want is when html button is pressed, the page runs the python code and shows me the decoded text but when html button is pressed the webpage only shows the code in my py file but not runs it.

This is the python "new.py" code:

```
from flask import Flask

import os

import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/stop/")

def test():

    os.system('Python CN_Project.py')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am a beginner in networks ans python. Please help me.

Comment: For one, Python in `os.system()` is uppercase. This will not work. Two, flask has a response object, which returns the content to the browser, and here you have no response object, just that system command. Three, there is no button here. So, that means you are using a web server other than Flask's development server. Are you integrating with apache? Are you using mod_wsgi? Where is your HTML page that submits the request and handles the response?

Comment: I have made a simple html page which is:

<title>Test</title> 
 <a href="C:\Python27\CN_project.py" class="btn btn-info" role="button">stop</a>

Comment: This is not going to work. You can't just point to the python interpreter itself (which is lowercase `python` not `Python`, and if you're on windows it ends with .exe. It looks like you're pointing to a folder, here, not even a program at all. Why don't you just follow the quick start guide on flask's website? Flask comes with a development server, where you can make flask serve your HTML button page instead of it being a local file.

Comment: In order to get a cgi script working, you need a webserver installed. Your web browser isn't going to know how to execute a python script. You can install Tomcat for windows, but I recommend just using flask's development server, as configuring Tomcat to work with flask is probably more than you're going to be up for right now. Go back to flask's quick start guide and replicate that verbatim, then change little things until you have an idea for what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going through the [Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/) yet to get something simple working?

In the [template](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/templates/), you can create a link to a python function:

`<a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">log in</a>`

Yours would look like:

`<a href="{{ url_for('test') }}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">stop</a>`

And then in your [view](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/views/), new.py, import your python file as a module and call the function in there that decodes the image and returns the text.

```
from flask import Flask
from CN_Project import decode_text_from_image
...

@app.route("/stop/")
def test():
    output_text = decode_text_from_image('hardcoded_image.jpg')
    return render_template('my_page.html', text_to_render=output_text)
...
```

Then you want to render the output text in your html [template](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/templates/):

`<p>{{ text_to_render }}</p>`

For now, work on just using an image that is hardcoded into your python function. Afterwards, you can deal with passing in the image, maybe through a filepicker.

References:

[Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/)

[Flask templates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/templates/)

[Flask view functions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/views/)

Comment: I shifted from decoding to simply print a hello world on webpage by implementing all you said above but when I press the html button it says your file was not found.

Comment: If you are calling a function that takes a path to a file as an argument, then that might by your problem (like if you have hardcoded a file that has the wrong path).

In general, if you are getting an error message, search for it in stack overflow to narrow in on the problem. Also, it sounds like you should really just do the Flask tutorial first to get the basics.